# Cross-platform C++ - any reason to prefer _ltoa when it's available?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, cross-platform

I've recently started working on a C++ project originally developed by others.

Looking at old copies of source code on different platforms, it appears that `_ltoa` has been used in the Windows version, but the code has been manually changed to use `sprintf` each time a new Linux build is required.

I could use `#if defined` to avoid the manual change for each platform, but is there any reason to do this instead of just using `sprintf` on all platforms?
Is `_ltoa` in any way "better" when building for Windows?

**Edit:**
Even though this code is C++, I'd prefer to stick to C functions for this specific type conversion, because the resulting char-array is passed to the JNI function `NewStringUTF`.
I could use `std::to_string`, then use `string::c_str()` to get a char-array, but that's an extra, unnecessary, function call.

Comment: The title says C, the question body and the tags say C++. Which one is it? In C++, the best option is `std::to_string`.

Comment: I've changed the title. It is C++, though C functions have been used in many places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sprintf` in theory may be a bit slower due to the extra complexity given by the format string. In practice, most modern compilers are able to parse the format string and, in simple cases, resolve it themselves to the appropriate function call (some `ltoa`-like in this case).

Thus, I'd use `sprintf` and avoid messing with implementation-specific stuff.

Comment: Good enough. I'll go with that.